# Call aws-lambda recursively in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, recursion, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora

I want to fetch product ids from Aurora mysql and send them to SQS by using lambda.

Pseudo code:

```
int limit = 90,000;
int offset = 0;

//set db connection
query = ("select product id from products limit " +limit + " offset " + offset);
while(rs.next())
{
pid = rs.getString(1);
...
//code to send pid to sqs 
}

if(context.getRemainingTimeInMillis() < 10000)
{
//call this lambda again
offset = offset + limit;
//call same lambda with updated offset and repeat this until all the records are fetched
}
```

I have no idea how to call aws-lambda `recursively` so that the sql query would pick up the updated offset everytime. And how to do error handling in this lambda so that if some lambda fail then it should retry again. The total pids in my table are around 7 million and in 1 invocation I am able to send 90k records to queue.

Comment: Are you unable to process everything within a 15 minute Lambda?

Comment: Yes for 7 million it doesn't complete in 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a job for Lambda. I would probably turn to using AWS Batch or an ECS Task first.

And there are some improvements that you can make to your current code. It looks like you're sending 1 message at a time to SQS, but you can send up to 10.

And depending on how you process the messages, it might make sense to batch them up yourself into messages that contain 1,000 or more IDs.

But if you're set on using Lambda and writing individual SQS messages, then you need to understand the [invoke()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/AWSLambda.html#invoke) operation. You will want an asynchronous invocation, and you'll need to package the offset in a JSON blob.

If you go this route, I recommend moving the time check into the loop: for each record processed, increment the index variable. After sending the message, check the time and invoke the function again if necessary, passing the current index. Then break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to implement recursion in serverless is using scheduled lambdas.
Basically you will have a lambda that runs say every 15 minutes.

Regarding the `offset` I would recommend marking the records as processed instead of trying to pass around the offset parameter.

Your query will look like this:

```
query = ("select product id from products WHERE processed=false AND limit=" +limit);
```

Then we need to answer the question, *when do we stop the scheduled lambda?*
If you have finite number of records you can just disable the cloud watch rule that triggers the lambda periodically once you know that all records are processed, otherwise we are good we want the lambda to run forever :)

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-rule.html) on how to trigger lambdas on schedule.

Comment: But how will I update processed and not processed in db? And won't that be permanent like if I'll run lambda the next day, the processed will be true for every product id right?

Comment: Yes, it will be permanent. Do you want to process a record every day? if so then it might be better to persist processedDate flag. Then you will process a record if processedDate != today